# Multiple TFS servers and mapping

Tags: tfs, mapping, tfvc

We have two TFS servers, I have mapped a project on server1 now I want to map  another project from server2 but my workspace is pointing to  tfs server1. This scenario is working on others machines, please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the workspace by selecting it as the screenshot below:

[image]

You can remove the workspace pointing to tfs server1, and add a new one.

Answer (score 0):

You need to first create a new workspace to map to Server2, then get latest version for that 'another project' to the workspace.